# Qt web engine get history

Tags: c++, qt

I am reading a Qt book, which may not be so good, that is giving me some troubles. I need to get the history from a `QWebEngineView* webview;` I have written this code following the book:

```
 QWebEngineHistory* h = QWebEnginePage::history();
```

This is how I should retrieve the history and then I can access it using `h->items();`. The problem is that the above code produces

> call to non-static member function without an object argument

How can I fix this? I need to get the history of the navigated pages

---

I have then tried this

```
QWebEngineHistory* h = webview->history();
```

But now I am not able to call `h->items()`. How can I fix this? I need to access `items()`.

**Header file**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebEnginePage>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow() override;
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_4_clicked();
    void on_url_input_returnPressed();
    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_7_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_6_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWebEngineView* webview;
    void loadPage() const;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Implementation**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    ui->setupUi(this);

    webview = new QWebEngineView(ui->webViewFrame);
    loadPage();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked() {
    webview->back();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked() {
    webview->forward();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    webview->reload();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked() {
    loadPage();
}

void MainWindow::loadPage() const {
    QString url = ui->url_input->text();

    if (url.length() == 0)
        url = "http://www.google.it";

    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
        url = "http://" + url;

    ui->url_input->setText(url);
    ui->listWidget->addItem(url);
    webview->load(QUrl(url));
}

void MainWindow::on_url_input_returnPressed() {
    loadPage();
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QMainWindow::paintEvent(event);
    webview->resize(ui->webViewFrame->size());
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked() {
    QWebEngineHistory* h = webview->history();
    auto x = h->items(); //error here!!

    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_7_clicked() {
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_6_clicked() {
    ui->listWidget->clear();
}
```

Comment: `QWebEngineHistory* h = QWebEnginePage::history();` this book is full of errors :(

Comment: `items()` is a method of _QWebEngineHistory_. Once you have a pointer to an object of that class, `h`, you should be able to access this method. I think something else is wrong here. How do you know that you can't call `h->items()`?

Comment: Becayse when I call h->items() I get this error "Member access into incomplete type QWebEngineHistory"

Comment: place `#include <QWebEngineHistory>` in the include section of your implementation file.

Comment: @scopchanov now it works!! The book said that is was not needed because it made a call to QWebEnginePage and so #include <QWebEnginePage> was enough.

Comment: or after `#include <QWebEnginePage>` in your __MainWindow.h__ if you preffer.

Comment: Definely I am getting another book after this, from another author...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177420/discussion-between-raffaele-rossi-and-scopchanov).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not that big expert for Qt. But I think your book has a mistake in this case. Your second approch

```
QWebEngineHistory* h = webview->history();
```

is perferctly correct. Because you want to retrieve the history from your web engine (object `webview`).

From the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) `history()` is a non-static function. (That's why your first code produces the specified error.) If `history()` would be a static function, what history should it return? It hasn't any connection to a web view.

**Edit (requested by scopchanov):** In *qwebenginepage.h* `QWebEngineHistory` is only forward declared, hence you need to `#include <QWebEngineHistory>` to access `items()` (or any other method for that matter).

Comment: And that's good! But still for some reasons I cannot access h->items()

Comment: @scopchanov: Thanks for adding this hint.